# Why does html from requests response deviate from dev tools?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape [houzz website](https://www.houzz.com.au/professionals/home-builders/turrell-building-pty-ltd-pfvwau-pf%7E1099128087)

In browser dev tools it shows HTML content. But when I scrape it with beautifulsoup, it returns something else together with some of the html, I do not have much knowledge on this.

A **little part** of what I get is as follows.

```
</div><style data-styled="true" data-styled-version="5.2.1">.fzynIk.fzynIk{box-sizing:border-box;margin:0;overflow:hidden;}/*!sc*/
.eiQuKK.eiQuKK{box-sizing:border-box;margin:0;margin-bottom:4px;}/*!sc*/
.chJVzi.chJVzi{box-sizing:border-box;margin:0;margin-left:8px;}/*!sc*/
.kCIqph.kCIqph{box-sizing:border-box;margin:0;padding-top:32px;padding-bottom:32px;border-top:1px solid;border-color:#E6E6E6;}/*!sc*/
.dIRCmF.dIRCmF{box-sizing:border-box;margin:0;display:-webkit-box;display:-webkit-flex;display:-ms-flexbox;display:flex;-webkit-box-pack:justify;-webkit-justify-content:space-between;-ms-flex-pack:justify;justify-content:space-between;-webkit-align-items:center;-webkit-box-align:center;-ms-flex-align:center;align-items:center;margin-bottom:16px;}/*!sc*/
.kmAORk.kmAORk{box-sizing:border-box;margin:0;margin-bottom:24px;}/*!sc*/
.bPERLb.bPERLb{box-sizing:border-box;margin:0;margin-bottom:-8px;}/*!sc*/
```

What should I do with this? Is not this achievable with beautfulsoup?

Comment: Seems to be fine - Please improve your question and tell as what you exactly expect. Some code would also be nice.

Comment: My problem is that, this kind of content is not showing when I inspect the page. Why I am getting this when I am trying to scrape?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Developer Tools operate on a live browser DOM, what you’ll see when inspecting the page source is not the original HTML, but a modified one after applying some browser clean up and executing JavaScript code.

`Requests` is not executing JavaScript so content can deviate slightly, but you can scrape - Just take a deeper look into your soup.

#### Example (project titles)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


url_news = " https://www.houzz.com.au/professionals/home-builders/turrell-building-pty-ltd-pfvwau-pf~1099128087"
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Safari/537.36'}

response = requests.get(url_news, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")

[title.text for title in soup.select('#projects h3')]
```

#### Output

['Major Renovation & Master Wing',
'"The Italian Village" Private Residence',
'Country Classic',
'Residential Resort',
'Resort Style Extension, Stone and Timber',
'Old Northern Rd Estate']